# What's the right HQL Syntax for this query?

Tags: hql

I have a class `GameDefinition` that extends `ItemDefinition`.
I also have other classes that extend `ItemDefinition`.
I have another class `StoreItem` that has an attribute named `itemDefinition` of type `ItemDefinition`.

I want to find all `GameDefinitions` joined to their `StoreItems`.  But of course, I don't want to get other definitions that extend `ItemDefinition`.

In raw sql I would expect something like this to work.

```
select * from game_definition g
inner join store_item s on g.id=s.item_definition_id
```

What is the proper `HQL` way for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the HQL so much as configuring the mapping in the entity bean. Assuming `GameDefinition` is an `@Entity`, something like this:

```
SELECT g FROM GameDefinition g
```

You'd configure the actual `StoreItems` with some sort of mapping (one-to-one, one-to-many, etc.) using the appropriate annotation. If, for example, the mapping was [one-to-one](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html):

#### `GameDefinition.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="game_definition")
public class GameDefinition implements Serializable
{
    // snip other fields...
    private StoreItem storeItem;

    // snip other getters/setters...

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "gameDefinition")
    public StoreItem getStoreItem()
    {
        return storeItem;
    }
    public void setStoreItem(StoreItem storeItem)
    {
        this.storeItem = storeItem;
    }
}
```

#### `StoreItem.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="store_item")
public class StoreItemimplements Serializable
{
    // snip other fields...
    private GameDefinition gameDefinition;

    // snip other getters/setters...

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_definition_id")
    public GameDefinition getGameDefinition()
    {
        return gameDefinition;
    }
    public void setGameDefinition(GameDefinition gameDefinition)
    {
        this.storeItem = gameDefinition;
    }
}
```

---

***Edit:*** you could actually do this with HQL, but then [`Query#getResultList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) would return a `List<Object[]>`, which would require casting, and be ugly, etc. Let me know if you want to see how this would be done.

Comment: But my store item doesn't point directly to the subclass.  It points to the super class.  And there can be many other kinds of objects that are store items.

Comment: Is the super class an `@Entity`?